# Change the Uri in WebBrowser.Navigating

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

Is it possible in the handler of the Navigating event to change the Uri to which the WebBrowser control is navigating ?

The Uri in the event arguments can not be changed, because it is read only, however, I tried to Cancel the navigation and send the browser to a new address with the Navigate method like this:

```
// I can not do this.
// e.Uri = new Uri( "http://newUri" );

e.Cancel = true;
( (WebBrowser)sender ).Navigate( new Uri( "http://newUri" ) );
```

however, this makes my application crash without any exception whatsoever.

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you try put `Navigate` method into `Dispatcher` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this is an emulator bug. My approach makes the app running on the emulator crash, but it works properly on a real device.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are causing a stack overflow. Each time the navigation event fires, you tell the browser to navigate again, which raises the event again ...

Try adding a boolean to stop your code recursing ...

```
private bool isRedirecting = false;

private void WebBrowser_OnNavigate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (isRedirecting)
    return;

  e.Cancel = true;

  isRedirecting  = true;
  ( (WebBrowser)sender ).Navigate( new Uri( "http://newUri" ) );
  isRedirecting = false;
}
```

Comment: I didn't show that part of the code, but I am checking on a condition already, which is true only in the first occurence of the event. I tried to debug it, and the Navigating event is fired only once.